# How to call instance variable form another class and file

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance-variables

I have a question, I have 4 file **app.py**, **face.py**, **camera.py** and **db.py** Inside **face.py** file I have one variable call **known_encoding_faces**. If I put print code inside my face.py and run the app.py the result will display in my command prompt.

My question is how can i use **known_encoding_faces** variable in my camera.py? My expected result is when i run my app.py and open my webcam the command prompt will show the printed **known_encoding_faces** output. I believe if this work means this **known_encoding_faces** variable successfully can be used by camera.py file.

Here I attach my code. Hope someone can help me regarding on this matter.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, Response, json, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import request
from os import path, getcwd
import time
from face import Face
from db import Database
app = Flask(__name__)
import cv2
from camera import VideoCamera


app.config['file_allowed'] = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg']
app.config['train_img'] = path.join(getcwd(), 'train_img')
app.db = Database()
app.face = Face(app)


def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def success_handle(output, status=200, mimetype='application/json'):
    return Response(output, status=status, mimetype=mimetype)
```

face.py

```
import face_recognition
from os import path
import cv2
import face_recognition



class Face:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.train_img = app.config["train_img"]
        self.db = app.db
        self.faces = []
        self.face_user_keys = {}
        self.known_encoding_faces = []  # faces data for recognition
        self.load_all()

    def load_user_by_index_key(self, index_key=0):

        key_str = str(index_key)

        if key_str in self.face_user_keys:
            return self.face_user_keys[key_str]

        return None

    def load_train_file_by_name(self,name):
        trained_train_img = path.join(self.train_img, 'trained')
        return path.join(trained_train_img, name)

    def load_unknown_file_by_name(self,name):
        unknown_img = path.join(self.train_img, 'unknown')
        return path.join(unknown_img, name)


    def load_all(self):
        results = self.db.select('SELECT faces.id, faces.user_id, faces.filename, faces.created FROM faces')
        for row in results:

            user_id = row[1]
            filename = row[2]

            face = {
                "id": row[0],
                "user_id": user_id,
                "filename": filename,
                "created": row[3]
            }

            self.faces.append(face)

            face_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(self.load_train_file_by_name(filename))
            face_image_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(face_image)[0]
            index_key = len(self.known_encoding_faces)
            self.known_encoding_faces.append(face_image_encoding)
            index_key_string = str(index_key)
            self.face_user_keys['{0}'.format(index_key_string)] = user_id

    def recognize(self,unknown_filename):
        unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(self.load_unknown_file_by_name(unknown_filename))
        unknown_encoding_image =  face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

        results = face_recognition.compare_faces(self.known_encoding_faces, unknown_encoding_image);

        print("results", results)

        index_key = 0
        for matched in results:

            if matched:
                # so we found this user with index key and find him
                user_id = self.load_user_by_index_key(index_key)

                return user_id

            index_key = index_key + 1
        return None
```

camera.py

```
import face_recognition
from os import path
import cv2
from db import Database
from face import Face

class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Using OpenCV to capture from device 0. If you have trouble capturing
        # from a webcam, comment the line below out and use a video file
        # instead.
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # If you decide to use video.mp4, you must have this file in the folder
        # as the main.py.
        # self.video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        success, image = self.video.read()
        # We are using Motion JPEG, but OpenCV defaults to capture raw images,
        # so we must encode it into JPEG in order to correctly display the
        # video stream.
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

Comment: You can import variables, doesn't that work?

Comment: @Nishant Doesn't work :(  I have try for for few day but fail..maybe you can show me an how the way to do. I can try edit my code

Comment: just look into your variable name properly. declared known_encoding_faces list in the face.py file I can't see the known_face_encoding variable in it.

Comment: @VaradarajuG I already declare in my face.py file 

self.known_encoding_faces = []. I believe it instance variable

Comment: then use same name for import

Comment: @VaradarajuG still show error ImportError: cannot import name 'known_encoding_faces' from 'face' (C:\tutorial\face_recognition\venv\src\face.py). Do i need to put self? ... I got this error when run my app.py

Comment: try to make as a global one

Comment: @VaradarajuG where should i declare it as global face.py? or camera.py

Comment: @VaradarajuG Thank for your effort sir.. Thanks for advice too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`known_encoding_faces`  is a member of a `Face` object. That means it does not exist on its own - as evidence, note you only reference `self.known_encoding_faces` rather than just `known_encoding_faces`. You need to initialize some `Face` object, and than you can use it. Further more, it looks like you would need to call `load_all` on said object to properly initialize it. The minimal thing you need is some thing like:

```
from face import Face

aface = Face(app) #You would need an app here
aface.load_all()
known_encoding_faces = aface.known_encoding_faces
```

If you are expecting this to exist irrespective of an objects creation, you need to rethink your design, and take it out of your class.

If you are expecting this to be called from the main script, you can demand this variable to initialize your camera:

```
VideoCamera(app.face.known_encoding_faces) #Called from main script
```

and in `camera.py`:

```
class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self,known_face_encodings):
        self.known_encoding_faces = known_face_encodings
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

and in this class you can now use `self.known_encoding_faces`.

Comment: Thanks for advise. Currently I already put this code but doesn't work.. I believe it almost. As you mention may I know how can i get the app so that my aface.face(app) can be executed? Where i should place it in my app.py?

Comment: @iszzulikhwan91 look at the second example.  Change `VideoCamera` to take this list in its `init` method, and then when you create a `VideoCamera` in your `app.py`, just send it `app.face.known_encoding_faces` which is already initialized.

Comment: Thank you very much @kabanus. The code works well. Thanks you so much sir for our effort. I really appreciate it. Sir I interested to know about the first solution you provided. If i want to used it. Do i need to put in app.py?

Comment: @iszzulikhwan91 You would need it in `camera.py` since that is where you want to use it. But then you would need to initialize and `app` and a `Face`. I am not sure that makes sense in your context, since they already exist in `app.py` by the time you initialize the `VideoCamera`. You would have to create the `app` and `Face` in `camera`, which I do not think makes sense. That is why I would use the second solution -

Comment: you mention that I have to initialized and app and face. I try this method before but it show error. That why I am interested to know. In my case how to initialize the app. Do I need to declare this  app = Flask(__name__) again?

Comment: @iszzulikhwan91 Yes. All the names you use in `camera.py` need to defined in `camera.py` - or be sent to the `VideoCamera` directly.

Comment: @iszzulikhwan91 The second solution is literally adding one and a half lines of code to the `VideoCamera`, and changing one call in `app.py`. I'm unsure why you so opposed.

Comment: Yeah sure sir... I will use the second solution. I just want know why I fail before since i used the first solution before. Based on your solution I clearly understand why I getting fail before. I just want to know the root problem make me fail. But thanks again to you sir. Hope you can advise me again in my next posting. :)